# pdf2json npm package is not extracting the data in paragraph is there any alternate npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried with pdf2json npm package to extract the data from a pdf but it not extracting the data in paragraphs.

I have a pdf document which contains tables, paragrphs and charts init, i want to extract the raw data as a text file.

is there any alternate option to extract the data from pdf in paragraphs using Node js.

Comment: What is currently happening when you try to use the pdf2json package? There could also be a specific format pdf files need to be in for the package to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdf-parse` npm package to get the raw text content. Here is the link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

"pdf-parse" would do that alien to pdf, concept of paragraphs however that package seems long abandoned.

For a fork, still recently maintained, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfdataextract

"pdfdataextract" will output lines combined, in fact the complaint is, it does not preserve the natural single lines that are in a valid raw PDF extraction.